# Is there a standard and an implementation for Icalendar event RSVP

Tags: php, email, notifications, icalendar, rfc

The summary is that I am now implementing an event confirmation system and can't find the right format for the ICalendar replies. Therefore I wonder if there is an example out there of complete REPLY message and maybe a PHP library that would wrap it all?

Now for the details, we get external emails including event invitations asking for RSVP. Here is an excerpt of the iCal file:

`ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN="'user@company.com'":MAILTO:user@company.com ORGANIZER;CN="Organ Izer":MAILTO:organizer@company.com`

I couldn't find the reply standard to send the RSVP to the organizer. The [RFC 2447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.12) mentions "ATTSTAT" and "PARTSTAT" parameter.

By trying to mail the following message to Google calendar the event is not being updated.

```
$headers = "Content-Type:text/calendar; Content-Disposition: inline; charset=utf-8;\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
$headers .= 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REPLY
BEGIN:VEVENT
ORGANIZER;CN=JCharles:mailto:abcdef@gmail.com
UID:oc7ae7537999onscsivg8km123@google.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=CONFIRMED;RSVP=
 TRUE;CN=jc@company.se;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:mailto:jc@company.se
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:1
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR';

mail('abcdef@gmail.com', 'Accepted:', "Event accepted", $headers);
```

Is there anything wrong with the Ical message or with the method in itself? Is this the way the event replies are supposed to be sent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code will work with google calendar. The attachment is processed by gmail and acceptance is cascaded to the event.

```
$vcal = 'BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//EXAMPLE.NU//SE
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REPLY
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20101215T160000Z
DTEND:20101215T170000Z
DTSTAMP:'.date('Ymd\THis\Z').'
ORGANIZER;CN=Jean-Charles:mailto:example@gmail.com
UID:u2coh5g3bppo2d2o3t@google.com
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;
 CN=user@example.se:mailto:user@example.se
CREATED:19000101T120000Z
DESCRIPTION:äåÃ³ö
LAST-MODIFIED:'.date('Ymd\THis\Z').'
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:a new test
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
';

$vcal = utf8_encode($vcal);

require('lib/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->AddAddress('example@gmail.com', 'Jean-Charles');
$mail->Body = "HTML BODY";
$mail->AltBody = "Text body";
$mail->Subject = "Email title";
$mail->Sender = "User Name";
$mail->FromName = "user@example.se";
$mail->AddStringAttachment($vcal, 'meeting.ics', "base64", "text/calendar");
$mail->Send();
```

The important bits are

- Content-type : text/calendar
- METHOD:REPLY
- PARTSTAT:ACCEPTED|DECLINED
- UID

I am not sure that it is necessary to send back all redundant information (description, summary, dtend, dtstart)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me:

```
$mail->Subject = $name;
$mail->Body = $description; 
$mail->AltBody = $body; // ical format
$mail->Ical = $message; // ical format
```

This methods does not attach the ical format.