# How to get response of vcalendar meeting invitation request

Tags: php, icalendar, vcalendar

I am sending calendar meeting invitation via PHP by following code.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Stockholm:20150508T100000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Stockholm:20150509T110000
ORGANIZER;CN=Anlita:mailto:organizer@google.com
UID:101
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP= TRUE;CN=Sample:mailto:attendee@yahoo.com
DESCRIPTION:test description lorem ipsum
LOCATION: SWEDEN
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:TESTING timezones testing timezones
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

**Currently what i am doing**

I am getting response in organizer email and then I read emails and getting response programingly but that is not a standard way because response of each mail server is different.

**Problem in getting response**

How to get response in PHP for our website database when user clicks on accept or decline button? In another words, How to call PHP file when user clicks on meeting invitation accept or decline buttons.

I want same response should come from each mail server(Google/Yahoo/Outlook etc) so that my common code should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get response of meeting invitation email in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514363/how-to-get-response-of-meeting-invitation-email-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am bit late but this is not a perfect method that you are trying so you can achieve same target by using Google Service Account. In Google service account, user will use site's calendar to send and receive invitation.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will be sent back to you to the email address specified in the `ORGANIZER` field.

Comment: That is already happening. I am reading emails and getting response programingly but that is not a standard way because response of each mail server is different. I want when user clicks on accept/decline then I want to execute PHP code so that i can insert response in my database

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 'not a standard way', because it's literally _the standard way_ for this to work. If you want to execute PHP code when you get a response, you need to hook PHP into your mailserver.

Answer (score 0):

The RSVP emails that will get sent to the organizer will have a similar `VCALENDAR` chunk, that will have the appropriate `ATTENDEE` line updated with the attendance, like:

```
ATTENDEE;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;CN=Sample:mailto:attendee@yahoo.com
```

Note that the `UID` will have to match the original invite, and the `METHOD` will have changed to `REPLY`.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4438206/2124628